# Is an injective statistic always sufficient?

Tags: sufficient-statistics, factorisation-theorem

New to the concept of sufficient statistics. Does it follow, in general, from the factorization theorem that any injective statistic is necessarily a sufficient statistic? I cannot find anything citing/stating this (probably obvious) result, and so I don't trust myself...

Comment: I would understand "injective" to mean you can recover the sample from the value of the statistic.  But since that makes the answer obvious, I wonder whether you intend "injective" to mean something else: what would it be?

Comment: Haha, exactly this. I figured it was just too obvious for anyone to state, but wanted a quick sanity check.